# How to never lose a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, backup, google-chrome-extensions

How can I make sure that I won't lose a Chrome extension?

A lot of things can result in the loss of a Chrome extension. For instance, the author can take it down or perhaps decide to charge money for it. Another scenario might involve an undesired update, although this is less of an issue as an older version could be downloaded.

Is it possible to somehow save a Chrome extension, so that I can be certain I always will have access to the Chrome extension. Or would that not be advised duo to the fact, that the Chrome extension might not continue to work with never versions of the Chrome Browser?

Answer (score 1):

Download the extension to zip file with a chrome extension downloader and unzip the file, then go to extensions and turn on developer mode. Click on load unpacked extension and select your unzipped folder.

This should keep it installed and will not auto update.

To disable developer extension warning see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome).

Comment: By doing that, is it likely that the Chrome Extension someday ceases to work duo to incompatibilities with newer versions of the chrome browser?

Comment: Maybe. But as long as it is still free and updated you can download newer versions.